# AttributeError: 'DataStore' object has no attribute 'fast_hash'

Tags: python, pickle, attributeerror

I recently updated all of my python libraries and now i want to load in some older pickle file. I did not changed my python version, i just updated my libraries. When i try to load in the file with the pickle module, i always get the following error message:

*AttributeError: 'DataStore' object has no attribute 'fast_hash'*

I am just using this line of code:

```
with open(path, 'rb+') as fileLoaded:
    loadedFile = pickle.load(fileLoaded)
```

Before i updated all of my python libraries, everything was working without any issues. Maybe someone knows this error.

Comment: Update: This issue is related to an update of the trimesh library in version 3.15.2. It is not working if you try to pickle across different versions of objects.